# Script only running on Active Object, not whole Selection?

Tags: scripting, objects

I am trying to make a script to Clear Custom Split Normals on all the objects I have selected. I have copied code from other scripts that run a command on all selected objects. However, this only seems to work on the Active Object, not the rest of the selection. Anyone know why?

```
import bpy

selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

for selected_object in selected_objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()
```

Is this a problem with my script, or with bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()? I am trying to make this a script because selecting everything an Alt clicking the button for it does not work on all objects either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the code ported to 2.8 ;)

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

selected_mesh_objects = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']

ao = context.view_layer.objects.active

for o in selected_mesh_objects:
    context.view_layer.objects.active = o
    r = bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()
    print(o.name, r)

# change ao back to original   
context.view_layer.objects.active = ao
```

Answer (score 4):

Set the active object in the loop, as it appears `bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear` only works on the active object. Not on all selected.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene

selected_mesh_objects = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']

ao = context.active_object

for o in selected_mesh_objects:
    scene.objects.active = o
    r = bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_custom_splitnormals_clear()
    print(o.name, r)

# change ao back to original   
scene.objects.active = ao
```

Note added print statement with name and operator "result".  A `{'FINISHED'}` set will indicate object had custom split normals and they have been removed.

Comment: Last suggestion doesn't work in latest 2.8. I think the problem is in the new API. Can you help with upgrading the code? I want to apply my script to the selected active object.