# Update to - "Create copies of primitives a number of times along a given or random length between two primitives"

Tags: modeling

I asked the above question some time ago

[Create copies of primitives a number of times along a given or random length between two primitives](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30944/create-copies-of-primitives-a-number-of-times-along-a-given-or-random-length-bet)

and received a perfect soultion from Dealga McArdle (zeffi). I am now using 2.80 and the code nolonger works. Not sure how to contact the originator but would be grateful if this was notified to them to see if they could possible do an update. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: could you explain more in depth and maybe point out the solution you're talking about?

Comment: @zeffi to notify via the bse inbox. Can also create github account and write to issues page https://github.com/zeffii/B3D_PrimitiveRepeat/issues  I'm not sure re the best way to handle questions re upgrading from prior version. .  Personally would bump the old question asking for conversion. There is a smaller set of the changes required, vs duplicating each question.  A new answer, or an edit from zeff, is worth an upvote, wouldn't remove the accept from the OP.   [_grumble_ example](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/89690/script-only-running-on-active-object-not-whole-selection)

Comment: Best way would have been to comment on original question, I think.